# Return map values sorted by keys

Tags: apache-spark, sorting, dictionary, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

Here is a simple example

```py
from pyspark.sql.functions import map_values
df = spark.sql("SELECT map('a', 1, 'c', 2, 'b', 3) as data")
df.show(20, False)
df.select(map_values("data").alias("values")).show()
```

[image]

What I want is the following (in the order of the keys: 'a', 'b', 'c')

[image]

How to achieve this?  In addition - does the result from `map_values` function always maintain the order in the `df.show()` above, i.e., `[1, 2, 3]`?

Comment: The `map_values` function returns values in an arbitrary order. The [documentation](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/sql/index.html#map_values) mentions that it _returns an unordered array containing the values of the map_. So the results can vary between query executions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An option using [`map_keys`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/reference/pyspark.sql/api/pyspark.sql.functions.map_keys.html#pyspark.sql.functions.map_keys)

```py
from pyspark.sql import functions as F
df = spark.sql("SELECT map('a', 1, 'c', 2, 'b', 3) as data")
df = df.select(
    F.transform(F.array_sort(F.map_keys("data")), lambda x: F.col("data")[x]).alias("values")
)
df.show()
# +---------+
# |   values|
# +---------+
# |[1, 3, 2]|
# +---------+
```

Answer (score 0):

The `map`'s contract is that it delivers value for a certain key, and the entries ordering is not preserved. Keeping the order is provided by `array`s.

What you can do is turn your `map` into an `array` with `map_entries` function, then sort the entries using `array_sort` and then use `transform` to get the values. A little convoluted, but works.

```
with data as (SELECT map('a', 1, 'c', 2, 'b', 3) as m)
select
    transform(
        array_sort(
            map_entries(m),
            (left, right) -> case when left.key < right.key then -1 when left.key > right.key then 1 else 0 end
            ),
        e -> e.value
    )
from data;
```